# Extract Audio text notes to mp3 or flac

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have a audio embedded text file (.docx) How can I Extract Audio Notes from pre 2010 Word Version to MP3 or FLAC

Comment: You've embedded an audio file into a Word document, or a Word document into an audio file?

Comment: When you need to clarify or expand on your question, [edit] the question.  Do not post bits and pieces of the question as answers.

Comment: I have an audio file in to a word document. It means audio text file. Now i need that audio file which my grandmother embeded. I need her voice audio. My grandmother sing some songs and embeded it in a ms word document. may be ms word 07 or ms word 10 pre version. How can i make that text document into her singing mp3 or flac file

Comment: When you need to clarify or expand on your question, [edit] the question.  Do not post bits and pieces of the question as ***comments***, either.

Answer (score 2):

**I) Archive extraction method**

1. If you have a .doc file then just save it as .docx in Word
2. Change the file extension to .zip (since .docx files are just plain ZIP archives)
3. Look inside the various sub-folders for your media files, especially `word\embeddings` and `word\media`

**II) Save as HTML method**

1. Save the document (.doc or .docx) as a Web Page:

   [image: 1]
2. Look inside the folder accompanying the HTML file for your media files

**Note:** Using both methods embedded MP3s may be extracted as .BIN files, but you can simply change their extensions back.

Comment: I already use this 2 methods but i can not find any bin file or embedding file. Only .xml files are there. Can you explain what is the problem.

Comment: Why didn't you bother to mention this in the question then? If there's nothing but .XMLs inside the .DOCX then I can't help. But if the audio files are actually embedded then they *have* to be there inside, and they aren't saved as .XML, that's for sure.